# When would I post something to Programmers instead of Stack Overflow and vice versa?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, software-engineering-se

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange)

I've read the descriptions of both Stack Exchange's "Programmers" and "Stack Overflow" sites.  But it is not clear to me when I should ask a question on Programmers instead of Stack Overflow.  With the exception of THIS question, so far everything I've asked has been (mostly) technical in nature and I've always asked on Stack Overflow.  But I see lots of technical questions in Programmers.

Does anyone have a good rule of thumb for knowing when to post where?

Comment: Oops. I see what you Anthony means. I meant "Programmers" where I said "StackExchange". I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

The FAQs for each site should be explanatory enough, but the short short version is

- When you have an *actual* programming problem to solve, like a piece of code that doesn't work or something you just can't figure out how to do

  - ask it on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) ([FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq))
- When you want to talk about topics relevant to programmers (ie., learning, careers, etc.) but not an actual programming problem

  - ask on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) ([FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq))
- When you want to talk about how you might improve a piece of code

  - ask on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) (still in beta) ([FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq))
- When you want to talk about Fight Club

  - Take it to [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) ([FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq))